# LIMIT operator and error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table with columns ClientID `NUMBER (15,0)`, ProductPrice `NUMBER (15,0)`, ProductQuantity `NUMBER (21,0)`, ProductName `VARCHAR2(50)`, BuyDate `DATE`

I do the script below to extract the ProductName, on which the each customer spent more money:

```
SELECT ClientID, MAX(ProductPrice * ProductQuantity) AS ForProduct
FROM TESTVIEW 
WHERE BuyDate BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2020','MM.DD.YYYY') AND TO_DATE('01.05.2020','MM.DD.YYYY')
GROUP BY ClientID
ORDER BY ClientID, ForProduct DESC LIMIT 1
```

However, I get error  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Without operator LIMIT it works correctly. What is the reason and how could I get the result that I need?

Comment: "*What is the reason*" - because - [as documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)  - Oracle doesn't support LIMIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT ClientID, MAX(ProductPrice * ProductQuantity) AS ForProduct,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY MAX(ProductPrice * ProductQuantity) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TESTVIEW 
      WHERE BuyDate BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-05'
      GROUP BY ClientID
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: HI ! Thanks for you answer! In this case it give me only the first row of the table. But I need the rows with max amount of money that were spent by each ClientIDs. I made edits in my question.

Comment: @hatorihanso . . . The attempt in your question does nothing like that, but I changed the answer based on your comment.